# How to make 2 forms on 2 separate threads in C# winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, c#-4.0, backgroundworker

I am developing an interface in my C# 4.0 winform application, to fire some sms in bulk. Each message content is different so that I have to fire messages one by one. I have a form from where the end user can shoot smss, it may be more than a thousand.

I want to manage a queue. If the user shoots a sms then it will be submitted to the queue and the queue will send sms one by one.

So I have to create a form to manage the queue. The problem is that I want my application to work normally and in the background the queue sends sms.

So how can I achieve this task? I have tried `BackGroundWorker`, but I don't know how to maintain a separate thread with a form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All forms must be on the UI thread.  The sending of the SMS should be performed by the `BackgroundWorker.DoWork` event.  The updating of the form is then done by `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted` event.

The UI thread is main thread of the application for SWF (winforms)

If you are using C# 4.0 or above, you may also want to investiage the Take Parallel Library (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx).  But I would first get BackgroundWorker implementation to work.  Then use TPL to send simultaneous SMS.  Could really speed things up.

Comment: is UI Thread is main thread ? please describe in brief your answer

Comment: As far as I know there is no restriction in itself that all forms must be created on the same thread. However, any interaction with a form must be performed on the same thread on which it was created. I haven't done this extensively though, so there may be some pitfall that I am not aware of.

Comment: I have a DataGridView on second form / queue form, when i use that datagridview in background worker then i got error message of cross thread reference. how to over come of this.

Comment: @FredrikMörk, I believe that Windows message pump will not deliver to forms on non-UI thread. I too have not extensively investigated it.

Comment: @HaiderAliWajihi You cannot access a control from a non-UI thread.  You need to collect the info from the datagrid and pass it to the background worker.

Comment: @RichardSchneider: I did some minor investigation a couple of years ago resulting in a blog post ( [A generic approach to a thread safe splash form](http://j.mp/VODpni) ), and it does seem to work fine. Still, it's seems like a very unusual case that creating the form on a separate thread would be a solution to a real problem. Your solution here is better; it also aims for separating work from presentation.

Comment: @Richard Schneider, Ok i gotted the formula how to achieve, please re-confirm my idea.
in background worker - runWorkerAsynch method send sms, in worker completed update the form and re start the worker again if sms is pending.

Comment: @Richard Schneider, Thank you, i am going to try this solution.

Comment: @Richard Schneider, again thanks for your suggestion about TPL.

Answer (score 1):

you have to create one thread (called worker thread) which runs for the life your application.

you have to have a queue or even better a concurrent queue http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx

the worker thread wait when an item (sms) appears in the queue, takes that item and do its work.

the UI is completely decoupled from that work.

this is most basic use of the class Thread.

Background worker is least suitable solution. obviously you can use a washing machines to build a house but most people use bricks.

Comment: In most cases a `BlockingCollection` is preferable to a `ConcurrentQueue` (it will wrap one by default though.  Also, I fail to see how using a BackgroundWorker isn't suitable.  It's a perfectly appropriate means of doing a long running task in a non-UI thread while managing progress/completion in the UI thread.

Comment: I am sorry. this multi-threading trivia. I dunno mate. read Richter or something. thread vs threadpool.. or ask Frederik and Richard - they like to discuss things.

Answer (score 0):

You can start Thread then create new instance of form on it (with no parent) and then start message loop (such code located in Main method of project's template).
Remember, any form (generally any GDI object) can be used only on thread that creates it. E.g you can't create child form on another thread, then parent's. Every GUI thread must run message loop.

Comment: Having multiple UI threads is a *very* bad idea, and should only be done if absolutely necessary.  It's not needed here.